# Prime number theorem approximations.

Tags: prime-numbers

Is $\pi(n)=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{\log n} \right\rfloor$ for infinitely many $n$? If so, are there any conditions that a set or progression contains infinitely many such $n$'s? Do they have a distribution or any properties?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Vlad In the [Non-asymptotic bounds on the prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) section of Wikipedia's "Prime number theorem" article, consider the part showing the inequalities of Pierre Dusart, especially the first one (i.e., on the left).

Comment: And when you've digested that link, Vlad, maybe you'll be able to write up and post an answer to your own question!

Comment: @Vlad FYI, you may wish to read the closely related post of [When does $\pi(x)$ cross $x/\log(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3770105/602049).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something related to what you want can be found in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1398.pdf). Here I prove that for infinitely many $n$ $$\pi(n)=\frac{n}{\lfloor\ln{n}-1/2\rfloor}$$ holds true.